# Cannot retrieve dependency from Jboss repository

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, jboss, ejb-3.0

I made an EJB 3.0 and a client.
This is the pom for my EJB:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>Jboss</id>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api-impl</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

But jboss-ejb3-ext-api and it's implementation cannot be retrieved :/
eclipse is telling me :

> The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library
>   'C:\usr\local\m2-repository\org\jboss\ejb3\jboss-ejb3-ext-api\1.0.0\jboss-ejb3-ext-api-1.0.0.jar' MyFirstMavenEjb

In my client I just added "jnp-client", and there is not problem about retrieving this one.
Any idea why I can't retrieve those 2 jars?
Thanks.

EDIT
I need this class: "org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.RemoteBinding" To use the @RemoteBinding.

Edit 2 : solution
after doing some "mvn clean install" in cmd I saw that maven was trying to download some transitie dependency..... 
FROM THE OLD JBOSS REPO. since it was denied acces it just stopped before downloading the final .jar

[image: forbidden acces to old repo]

Adding the following exlusions solved the problem (the jar wich acces is being denied)

```
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>gnu-getopt</groupId>
<artifactId>getopt</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
<groupId>apache-xerces</groupId>
<artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
<groupId>apache-xerces</groupId>
<artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
<groupId>wutka-dtdparser</groupId>
<artifactId>dtdparser121</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
<groupId>sun-jaxb</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

However isn't there a better solution?
I'm guessing that it's trying to get stuff from the old repo because this jar is not used anymore and a new one must be popular.

Comment: sorry, Jboss AS 5.1.0.GA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution,
In fact this repository is depreciated, meaning jboss managment don't want you to use what's in it anymore.

BUT, access to this repo can be granted if you add a profile to your maven settings.xml

add this profile :

```
<profile>
  <id>jboss-deprecated-repository</id>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-deprecated-repository</id>
      <name>JBoss Deprecated Maven Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</profile>
```

And don't forget to activate the profile by addind that betwen

```
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.jboss.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the jar you're looking for is in `$JBOSS_HOME/common/lib` so I would to the following to make it available in your Maven repo:
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=$JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/jboss-ejb3-ext-api.jar -DgroupId="org.jboss.javaee" -DartifactId="jboss-javaee" -Dversion="1.0.0" -Dpackaging=jar`

After doing that update your Maven dependency in Eclipse.

Comment: that would be a solution, but this I'm doing an internship and I've been ask to deliver a pom.xml able to download everything needed from the internet.

the guy coding for the project shouldn't have to to stuff in cmd to get his jar :/

Comment: @Elidosa ok, but somehow the file is downloadable from the Internet, it's included in the standard JBoss archive. I know It's a bit of a long shot though ;)

Comment: So, the jar is available in some online repo?

Comment: yes it's available here :
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;quick~ejb3-ext-api

I found the problem, for some reason the pom.xml from this jar is trying to get jars from the old Jboss repo.
I excluded them all and now it's working